# Is UUID without dashes/hyphens valid?

Tags: cryptography, uuid

I want to write simple regex to validate UUIDs, but I'm not sure about this small detail.

Wikipedia states:

> UUID is represented by 32 lowercase hexadecimal digits, displayed in
> five groups separated by hyphens, in the form 8-4-4-4-12 for a total
> of 36 characters (32 alphanumeric characters and four hyphens).

But couldn't find anything like it in [RFC spec document](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122).

So the question remains whether this UUID is valid: `f47ac10b58cc4372a5670e02b2c3d479`?

Comment: Valid for _what_? If you want to allow it, feel free.

Comment: To add on to what @SLaks said, it is still effectively a valid guid, but it may not be valid for parsing by most built-in methods, but it may also be valid there as well. You just need to test, or at worst, pad with hypens before parsing.

Comment: @SLaks - does it mean that specification doesn't really say anything about representation format? Which means Wikipedia is not accurate enough, as often.

Comment: @DarrenKopp - good point. Any problems with no-hyphens format and built-in methods? I'm pretty new to the subject, so don't have enough exp.

Comment: @Carlos well, i don't know, i have no idea what systems you are using. like i said, if there were to be a problem, just add the hyphens in before you pass them to a method like that

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The production in [RFC 4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#page-4) (section 3, page 4), defines UUID string representation as

```
UUID = time-low "-" time-mid "-"
       time-high-and-version "-"
       clock-seq-and-reserved
       clock-seq-low "-" node
```

where each internal component is hex-encoded.

Therefore, `f47ac10b58cc4372a5670e02b2c3d479` is not a valid UUID representation.

Comment: I was reading the document, but started from section 4, as thought that formal definition will not contain the info I'm looking for - but it does. If you've read whole document - good on you, but it's like pointing out, that whoever asking JS question, should read whole MDN documentation. It's a little bit pointless, and SO is perfect to ask such questions, because maybe there is someone who has already done it and can save you a lot of time.

Comment: The document is a bit strange in that it specifies "hex octets" which use (of course) two hex characters per octet (byte). So you will see 4-2-2-2-6 instead of 8-4-4-4-12.

Comment: @owlstead: Yes - you will see 4-2-2-2-6 in normal notation after conversion to e.g. ASCII, but notice that UUID is given in hex notation. You will not see any 'G' or other non-hex letters there. And that's why it's 8-4-4-4-12.

Comment: I thought I was explaining that to you :P

Comment: For example You can check that your string contains valid symbols:

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("f47ac10b58cc4372a5670e02b2c3d479");
        final String res =
            sb
            .insert(8, "-")
            .insert(13, "-")
            .insert(18, "-")
            .insert(23, "-")
            .toString();

UUID.fromString(res);

Method fromString() throw exception otherwise